# Clear SSL Cache on the Client or Server side

Tags: java, browser, client, ssl-certificate, server

I am currently working on project that requires SSL Communication. What I want that login  in page should prompt the user for their certificate (and it does, the first time). But when you click the 'Sign in' button on the Signed out page it's using the SSL state from the previous user and no certificate prompting occurs.

I do not want to clear SSL Cache after closing the browser or do it to manually in the browser.

I know that java script clears SSL Cache for the browser but it is not universal to all.

Is there any client or server side approach (for server side I only prefer java) to clear ssl cache.

Comment: What server would that be? Is it one you write code for yourself?

Comment: @EJP I am using Jboss 5 server